# Breaking up long lines of a var into multiple lines

Tags: php

What's a good way to do the below without repeating the var name on each line?

```
$foo = 
$foo .= '<div>Line 1</div>'.PHP_EOL;
$foo .= '<div>Line 2</div>'.PHP_EOL;
```

Can something like this be done? (This doesn't work)

```
$foo = 
  '<div>Line 1</div>'.PHP_EOL;
  '<div>Line 2</div>'.PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
$foo = 
  '<div>Line 1</div>' . 
  '<div>Line 2</div>';
```

Comment: Yes, like this. Thanks :-)